# iPhone 4s problems making calls

Tags: iphone, hardware

My original 4s had issues with phone calls. Half the time calls were made the person on the other end couldn't hear me. Took to Apple store and they gave me a new phone. I've had it 5 days and it has more issues then my 1st one. 50% of the time I make calls neither person can hear each other. I can't even hear it dialing the #, but I watch the call timer run as it does connect. Tried restoring the phone, but still no luck. Is it a hardware issue or AT&T issue? Anyone know?

Comment: that sounds like a bit of bad luck getting two faulty devices

Comment: Tom - ill close this since its not useful without any follow up. We can reopen it if you have an answer or further detail that might help people other than e info to get help with the phone provided by Matt

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an issue with the hardware of the phone. I'd take it back to the Apple Store and have them swap it again. Before you leave, make a few calls on the new phone and make sure the issue is resolved. I've seen this issue pretty frequently on iPhone 4/S's